# using regex to replace the value after =

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as given below

```
abcdefg=12345
abcdefg=551234
abcdefg=111323
abcdefg=567454
```

i want to replace it using a regular expression so that the value becomes

```
abcdefg=456789
```

i used following code to do that

```
str1=string.split('=')
line=str1[0]+'='+"456789"
```

is there any better way using regular expresiion

Comment: What is the matter with the way you have it now? It works perfectly fine.

Comment: what about other strings? Do you want to remvoe `g` and digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  import re
  x="abcdefg=12345"
  print re.sub(r"(.*?)=\d+",r"\1=456789",x)
```

Using pure re.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
text = 'abcdefg=12345'
head, sep, tail = text.partition('=') + "=456789"

>>> print head
abcdefg=456789
```

From the docs:

> partition(...) S.partition(sep) -> (head, sep, tail)
>
> Searches for the separator sep in S, and returns the part before it,
>   the separator itself, and the part after it.  If the separator is not
>   found, returns S and two empty strings.